# Creating IDW-rasters from each field in large point feature set using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, inverse-distance-weighted

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.2

I am trying to automate the process of making a raster (IDW tool) in model builder by iterating through fields as z-value. I saw some other question asking the same, and it seems that it couldn't be done that easy in ModelBuilder, and that Python was the way to go.

I have this point feature of 200+ points that all have around 70 fields of Z-values (elements). In the snip below, you can see fields with elements, and also fields with ID's and other that I don't want to make a IDW raster out of.

[image: IDW for Lithium]

So for Lithium, it would produce this raster:

[image]

Now, how would I go about doing this process for all fields, except the ones without elements?

If it's easier, I wouldn't mind just deleting the non-element rasters afterwards, if I could maybe name the raster set after the field name perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is to only list the element fields and no other. You can do this in multiple ways, for example:

- Manually listing the fields which are not element fields, example below. Or manually list all element fields
- Use a wildcard with listfields, for example if all your element fields start with some letter
- List fields with names shorter than 4 letters

Example (untested, I dont have spatial analyst, you will probably need to look at the [syntax for IDW](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/idw.htm) and adjust the parameters):

```
import arcpy
from os.path import join

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass' #Change
out_gdb = r'C:\outdata.gdb' #Change
not_elementfields = ['OBJECTID','SHAPE','RowID'] #Change

elementfields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.name not in not_elementfields]
#elementfields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if len(f.name)<4]
print(elementfields)

#Run code above first to get the listing correct, then run everything

for field in elementfields:
    print(f'Proccessing IDW for fieldname {field}')
    outIDW = arcpy.sa.Idw(in_point_features=fc, z_field=field, cell_size=5, power=0.5, 
                search_radius= RadiusVariable(12))
    outIDW.save(join(out_gdb,f'IDW_{field}'))
```

(This is also possible:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://sciencenotes.org/PDFs/elementlist.csv', names = ['number','symbol','element'])
elements = list(data.symbol)

elementfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.name.title() in elements] # title method will camelcase your field names, BE->Be, to match the csv file
```

)